# Calculating the arc length of a difficult radical function

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I am fairly new to calculus and self learning integration from home has been challenging so I'm sorry if I make any mistakes. I want to work out the arc length of:

$y = \sqrt{7.2 (x-\frac {1}{7}}) - 2.023, [0.213, 0.1.27]$.

I have used the definition of a definite integral and got

$\int_{0.075}^{0.58} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3.54}{\sqrt{7x-1}}\right)²} dx$ =$\int_{0.075}^{0.58} \sqrt{1+\frac{12.5316}{7x-1}} dx$

So far which I think is correct. How would I proceed from here? Would I use u-substitution and then a trigonometric substitution to eliminate the exponent? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hint: let $C = 12.5316$, and never write any more decimals in the rest of your work. You can plug in $C$ at the end. Similarly, I'll use $a$ and $b$ for the limits of integration. So you have
\begin{align}
I &= \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \frac{C}{7x-1}}~dx
\end{align}
First step is common denominator:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{7x -1 + C}{7x-1}}~dx
\end{align}
Now let $u = 7x + 1, du = 7 dx$ to get
\begin{align}
I 
&= \int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{7x -1 + C}{7x-1}}~dx\\
&= \int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{u + C}{u}}~\frac{1}{7}~du\\
\text{so that}\\
7I &= \int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{u + C}{u}}~du\\
\end{align}

At this point...you'd really like to get rid of that $C$, so let's let
$$
u = C\tan^2 v \\
du = 2C \tan v \sec^2 v ~ dv
$$
so that
\begin{align}
7I 
&= \int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{u + C}{u}}~du\\
&= \int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{C(\tan^2 v + 1)}{C \tan^2 v}}~2C\tan v \sec^2 v ~ dv\\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{\sec^2 v}{\tan^2 v}}\tan v \sec^2 v ~ dv; & \text{write out in sines/cosines...}\\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2 v}}{\frac{\sin^2 v}{\cos^2 v}}}\frac{\sin v}{\cos^3 v}~ dv; \\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sin^2 v}}\frac{\sin v}{\cos^3 v}~ dv \\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \frac{1}{\sin v}\frac{\sin v}{\cos^3 v}~ dv \\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \frac{1}{\cos^3 v}~ dv \\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \frac{\cos v}{\cos^4 v}~ dv \\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \frac{\cos v}{(1-\sin^2(v))^2}~ dv; & \text{subst $t = \sin v$} \\
&= 2C\int_{x=a}^{x=b} \frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2}~ dt;  \\
\end{align}
which is now an ordinary partial-fractions integral; when you're done, you'll have to backsubstitute for $t$, and then $v$, and then $u$ to finally get an expression in $x$ into which you can plug the limits $a$ and $b$.

This *does* feel like a long way around, and there's probably a far simpler approach...but this is the one that jumped out at me.

Comment: Wow, thank you this helped, but can't I convert the bounds from x to u to v and then t and plug them in the final integral in terms of t? Also, I have't fully gotten into partial-fractions integration but I know how to solve partial fractions and the fraction above. Is it the same procedure?

Comment: Sure, you can push the bounds forward, or back-substitute at the end -- you get the same result. I was a little glib in saying the sqrt(sin^2 u) = sin u, but in this domain, $\sin u$ is probably positive, so I feel safe. As for partial fractions: yep: write that quotient of polynomials as a sum of nicer quotients, each of which will be solvable by a log or a trig substitution or something like that.

Comment: By the way, DO check my work -- there's a good chance I messed something up in the algebra, which I did while typing!

Comment: The algebra seems fine. Thank you for your time. This integral was bothering me a lot.

Comment: I found a mistake. You let u = 7x+1 instead of 7x-1.

Comment: At the last line of the integration, how did you get -2C instead of 2C?

Comment: To be honest, I substituted $t = \sin v$ and $dt = \cos v$, but *thought*, as I was doing so, that I was substituting $t = \cos v$ and $dt = -\sin v ~ dv$, and pulled the minus sign to the front. In short, it should not be there, and I'll go back and edit it out.